# How to ask appior method to not show support, and confidence

Tags: r

I have the following code

```
library(arules)
rules<- apriori(df)
inspect(head(rules,10 ))
```

The result of inspect includes `lift`, `support`, and `confidence`, meanwhile i only need to have the lift.

So, **how can i ask inspect method to not show support and confidence?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
    as(rules,"data.frame")[,c(1,4)]
This gives you data frame of rules and just lift. No option is available in inspect for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the structure of the rules using `str(rules)` you can see that the lift is in there and accessible with `rules@quality$lift`